# cronjob to remove directories that are smaller than x in size

Tags: cron

I want to run a cronjob every 6 hrs that deletes directories smaller than 200MB. I know dh command would do the job, but i'm not sure how to use the command. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`find . -type d -size -200M` will return every directory smaller than 200MB, you can also give the `-maxdepth` parameter to avoid going recursively into those smaller directories.

To automatically remove them, pipe to xargs, e.g. `find . -type d -size -200M -maxdepth 1|xargs rm -rf`

Be sure to test this thoroughly before you actually pass the command to `rm`. There is no "undelete" or "trash" you can pull stuff back from!!!

Answer (score 1):

To complete Jakke answer, open crontab:

```
   crontab -e
```

and add this line:

```
   0 */6 * * * command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This will run `command` every six hours starting from 0, it is equivalent to:

```
   0 0,6,12,18 * * * command > /dev/null 2>&1
```

First 0 means first-last minute, you can change it if you like to start command at ith minute.

Both standard error and standard output are redirected to prevent cron sending mail.

Here is [crontab manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/crontab.5.html) link.